# Как работать с типом System::String?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

Допустим, если мне нужен двумерный массив из символов, стандартным std::basic_string я могу его создать следующим образом:

```
    string **table = new string*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
         table[i]=new string[n];
    }
```

Как осуществить тоже самое с String^?
И ещё как форматировать вывод, например, в textbox'е?
Извиняюсь за глупые вопросы, задали курсовую, которую нужно сделать на windows forms. В консоли всё сделал, а вот с окнами проблема :(

Answer (score 3):

Не надо писать `new string*[n];` в С++. Для таких задач есть `std::vector`, и правильный код выглядит так:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> table(n);
```

На С++/CLI это переписывается 1 в 1: `std::string` заменяется на `String^`, `std::vector<>` заменяется на `array<>^`:

```
auto table = gcnew array<array<String^>^>(n);
```

При этом не надо использовать `using namespace std;` чтобы не было конфликта с `std::array`. Однако в .NET традиция такова, что надо использовать `using namespace System;`.

Также обратите внимание на то, что тип переменной это указатель на массив - `array<T>^`, а создаем мы сам массив - `gcnew array<T>(n)` (без `^`).